# Local machine environment variable

Tags: postman

I have next problem: I have same environment for site on work and home PC, but I have different database records inside it.
So in that case for test requests on my local environment I constantly need to change tested values.

Postman has different scopes for variables (see [documentation](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/environments_and_globals/variables))

In my case in collection scope is saved production variables. On environment scope I rewrite this values by my local configuration.

#### Collection variables

**SITE_DOMAIN** - https://www.prod.com/
**USER_ID** - 1234567890

#### Environment variable

**SITE_DOMAIN** - https://dev.loc/
**USER_ID** - 123

At home I have the same domain, but another user id and I need to change it in Environment variable every time when I wanna run request at home.

I wanna setup **USER_ID** to another value only at home local machine.

[image]
[Recorded interface example](http://recordit.co/n4vJ5JcBRG)

Is it possible to rewrite variable with local machine scope? There is local layer, but it isn't described in documentation.

Comment: Can you not have more environment files with the values of the config you want to use local, rather than changing the same file each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see, **local variable** is that variable which we setup in **Pre-request Script** section in `pm.variables` scope.

So we can override environment value without changing it by

```
pm.variables.set("VAR_NAME", "VAR_VALUE");
```

Unfortunately it will run in all PC's on each send request. So we need to add some logic to it.

As it supposed by @Danny Dainton we can add some environment variable for dev PC position.

So as a workaround I add variable `PC_ENV` to **Local** environment and put some logic for this in **Pre-request Script** section.

```
if (pm.environment.get('PC_ENV') === 'home') {
    pm.variables.set("USER_ID", "35");
}
```

How can we use this? When we start work with Postman we go to our environment and setup **PC_ENV** value to **home** or **office** depends on where we are now.

[Recorded example](http://recordit.co/uNyjbcdqVT)

If we don't want to run Pre-script section every time we can add all local variables values for each PC and run it only once at the beginning of the work by setup required condition.

```
const needSetupEnvironment = true;//change to false when setup is finished
if (needSetupEnvironment) {
    const currentEnvironment = 'home';//setup environment before start work

    let userId;

    switch (currentEnvironment) {
        case 'home':
            userId = 35;
            break;
        default:
            userId = 123;
            break;
    }

    pm.environment.set('USER_ID', userId);
}
```

We can enable script when we need to change environment variables, and than disable it after setup run it once with correct environment.
[Recorded example](http://recordit.co/pGUrBl88nL)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly:

You could add a value into the local environment file `local_dev` or something, to run a check to see if it’s there - then have some logic in the `pre-request script` that looks for the value, if it exists, then change the USER_ID variable to the one you want before the request is made and if not, do nothing.

Roughly, something kind of like this but more elegant:

```
if(pm.environment.get('local_dev') === 'some_value') {
    pm.environment.set('USER_ID', 1234)
}
```

I might have totally misunderstood the question though.

Comment: The problem is that variable `local_dev` will be the same on all PC's cause Postman sync environment, so it can't check this value as constant. I found another solution for resolving this problem

Comment: Also I don't use environment files, cause it possible only in collection runner, but I need just to send request

Comment: You've used an environment file in your video example, not sure I understand. ;/ Adding something to the `pre-request` should change the variable value before the request is even sent so it shouldn't matter about syncing. You don't really need to check for a value in the file, you can just change the value via `pm.environment.set('USER_ID', 1234)` that you use locally.

Comment: Unfortunately `pm.environment` is common for all PC's. It changes in the Postman cloud. I provide a way of setup local value in my answer

Comment: The whole point of the environment files are to give you the ability to change this values from a dropdown option, rather than manually change the value each time yopu want to make a request. Having a local 'Pavlo's local var file' is perfect for this right?

Comment: But environment's isn't local? They are on every PC where Postman is setup with this account. They used to test quickly change values for prod, dev, local server. Now the problem was that I have similar local environment at office and at home, but I have some small different values and every time I need to change them manually.

Comment: It just seems to me that you are tying to add complexity into something actually quite simple but I'm not aware of your full context so I might be wrong. From your example, you seem to have taken part of my answer so you can just upvote it as it seems to be useful to you.

Comment: Ok. I will upvote. Actually I found Pre-script section before you answer, but it can be useful for others. So thanks for trying help me. Have a nice day :)

Comment: About complexity, I don't think so. Assume you have 10 environment variable. 8 of them are equal at home and office, and 2 are different. How could you resolve this situation? Make 2 environments? And what will be if you need to add some another common variable to your environment? Add them to both of them?

Comment: Like i said, I don't fully understand your context and I only would if is was in your team. One confusing thing is the home/office naming as the process you have in place, to need that separation when you basically mean local and producton (judging by the URLs in the OP) Writing problems out in a question is different than pairing on a solution, i'm sure if we were both in the same place it would be a simple thing to solve but you have a workaround now so it's all good :)